# Стратегия использования feature branches совместно с долгоживущей dev бранчей

Tags: git, git-branch

Дано: в master должен попадать только готовый функционал.

Разработка ведется в dev бранче, периодически ведется двухсторонний обмен коммитами между ними (rebase из master-а в сторону dev и merge из dev в master).

Этот воркфлоу работал до тех пор, пока были тривиальные последовательные изменения.

Возникли проблемы при реализации очень «долгой» фичи, которая предусматривает еще и несколько вариантов имлементации.

Т.е. мне нужно отвлекаться от реализации это фичи и делать другие вещи. Ес-но я должен коммитить незавершенные изменения из еще нереализованной фичи, чтобы обмен коммитами продолжал бы фунционировать.

Ясно, что нужно использовать несколько долгоживущие feature бранчи, ответвеленные от dev.

Предложение «сеньора» использовать stash (карманы) считаю в этом случае не очень хорошим.

Как мне дальше поступить?

Comment: я, честно говоря, мало что понял, но если у Вас есть долгая feature ветка, значит её нужно периодически обновлять из dev. Либо через merge, либо rebase — как больше нравится.

Comment: На основании [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/) я понял, что нужно **обязательно** делать `feature`-бранчи.

Comment: Нет ничего обязательного, нужно действовать согласно своим требованиям, а не тому, что на хабре написано. Да, работа через feature ветки удобна и я обратного ещё не видел. А Ваша проблема от этого яснее не стала, кстати

Comment: Я просто никогда не работал одновременно с двумя реализациями одной фичи. Первый вариант - это `quick and dirty` должен быть готов  быстрее, второй вариант реализации требует больше времени, хотя и более предпочтительней. Но его нужно делать только когда будет готов первый вариант.

Comment: сделайте две ветки, одна для быстрого варианта, другая для долгого — первую завершите и приступайте ко второй. Не понимаю я проблемы

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что то, что реализация фичи займет так много времени стало уже известно пост-фактум и нужно выделить эти изменения из общей  `dev` ветки в соответствующую `feature` ветку.

Comment: А что части нереализованной фичы делают в dev? Вы ведь её ещё не завершили и она должна быть в отдельной ветке.

Comment: Так это была моя ошибка: недооценен объем работы, не создана `feature`-ветка.

Comment: Ну а теперь правьте dev так, чтобы другие не страдали, потом выносите Ваши изменения в отдельную ветку и работайте. Ничего другого Вам делать не остаётся. Причём тут stash, кстати, тоже не ясно. Он тут вообще как может помочь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47317/discussion-between-hellboy-and-ixsci).